# Azure cli not creating role

Tags: azure, azure-cli

I am trying to follow this guide and am having no luck on the `az ad sp create-for-rbac --role="Contributor" --scopes="/subscriptions/${SUBSCRIPTION_ID}"` step. It gives me the error below. I have tried re-logging in and no luck there either. I have put in the subscription ID from when I logged in, as well.

Suggestions?

```
Role assignment creation failed.

role assignment response headers: {'Content-Length': '102', 
'Strict-Transport-Security': 'max-age=31536000; 
includeSubDomains', 'x-ms-failure-cause': 'gateway', 'X- 
Content-Type-Options': 'nosniff', 'x-ms-request-id': 'cac21e0b- 
021d-416f-a4a0-9f539fdf3be4', 'Expires': '-1', 'x-ms-correlation- 
request-id': 'cac21e0b-021d-416f-a4a0-9f539fdf3be4', 'Pragma': 
'no-cache', 'Cache-Control': 'no-cache', 'Date': 'Thu, 14 Jun 2018 
11:57:42 GMT', 'x-ms-routing-request-id': 
'NORTHCENTRALUS:20180614T115743Z:cac21e0b-021d-416f- 
a4a0-9f539fdf3be4', 'Content-Type': 'application/json; 
charset=utf-8'}
```

The subscription 'providers' could not be found.

Comment: If you want to create the role, you need to have the privilege to do this. So you need to check first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the look of it you are not assigning role to anything and the syntax might also be wrong.

```
az ad sp create-for-rbac -n "MyApp" --role contributor --scopes /subscriptions/{SubID}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, it sorta helps. It gives me a new error message now though, I think this one is one that my coworker needs to fix. `The client 'EMAIL' with object id 'SubID' does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/write' over scope '/subscriptions/SubID'.`